# Excel formula with a 3 tiered IF structure

Tags: excel-formula

new to formulating in excel and this one is a little too advanced.

Our business charges fees based off of a dollar amount the client has with us. The structure is:

- first 500,000 is (amount x .01),
- second 500,000 is (amount after 500,000 x .0075)+ 5000 from the 1st tier,
- third is anything above 1,000,000 is (amount above 1M x .005) + 8750 from tier 1 and 2.

Basically, if someone has 475,000 then I'm looking to get the answer 4,750. If they have 560,000 then I'm looking to get the answer 5,450. If they have 3,750,000 then I'm looking to get the answer 22,500.

Hopefully, this makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Choose and Match:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(A1,{0,500000,1000000}),A1*0.01,(A1-500000)*0.0075+5000,(A1-1000000)*0.005+8750)
```

[image]

---

Or just straight math:

```
=MIN(A1,500000)*0.01+(MAX(MIN(A1,1000000)-500000,0))*0.0075+MAX(A1-1000000,0)*0.005
```

[image]